# Can terraform enable Azure resource providers?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Resource providers in Azure for example Microsoft.Storage, Microsoft.Network needs to be enabled before I can create those resources. I couldn't find a relevant terraform resource to register these ? Can terraform enable them ?

NOTE: Just getting started in terraform.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, it seems there is no feather in terraform to enable the Azure resource. Terraform just provide you the feather that how to manage the resources for Azure. You need to ask the manager of the subscription to enable it for you. Or you can enable it yourself in Azure with the right permission, I think you need the Owner permission.

Comment: yup, that's what I'm currently doing using azure-cli. I was wondering if there is a way with terraform.